# How to store data offline in android database after parsing it from json through URL?

Tags: android, json, rest, android-studio, android-syncadapter

I want to store data locally in the phone after parsing it from JSON API and then make a button to synchronize that data whenever I need to so that the content can be used offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store data object locally, then you can make use of **Realm DB**. Below link explains how to use Realm DB https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-realm-database-replacing-sqlite-core-data/

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the best option to store bunch of data locally is using sqlite. You can search for it. There is a bunch of tutorials for it. Also, you can also use `Room` library which makes it really easy to create sqlite databases and interact with it.